# Window.setCaption(String) in vaadin does not support HTML

Tags: vaadin

Vaadin's Window extends Panel. A call to Window.setCaption() simply calls Panel.setCaption() which does support HTML. When I call Window.setCaption(), however, HTML is not supported. Not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client side (gwt) code for the caption handling is different. The VWindow class uses Util.escapeHTML() on the caption VPanel does not.

VWindow.java:

```
 public void setCaption(String c, String icon) {
    String html = Util.escapeHTML(c);
    if (icon != null) {
        icon = client.translateVaadinUri(icon);
        html = "<img src=\"" + Util.escapeAttribute(icon)
                + "\" class=\"v-icon\" />" + html;
    }
    DOM.setInnerHTML(headerText, html);
}
```

VPanel.java

```
public void setCaption(String text) {
    DOM.setInnerHTML(captionText, text);
}
```

Comment: You seem very knowledgeable about this; I am a newbie.

My reason for asking was to put an icon button in the header that can be clicked just like the "x" button is to close the window. I can find no provision for this in the API.

How hard would it be to create my own version of a vaadin window and put my customized buttons in the header using "X" as a template of sorts?

Comment: I just checked the sources after seeing your question, but I really don't know how hard it would be to extend the vaadin window.